# How to render html with highcharts in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, ionic2

I have tried to do this but wont able to set the positions as shown in the example what i want to do with ionic 2.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh2dhsfr/)

What i tried is this in my export class :

```
this.chart1 = {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
      },
      series: [{
        data: [14,14],
        size: '100%',
        innerSize: '95%',
      },
        {
          data: [21,7],
          size: '82%',
          innerSize: '95%',

        }]
    }, function(chart1) {
        var renderer = chart1.renderer,
            series1 = chart1.series[0],
            series2 = chart1.series[1],
            r1 = series1.points[0].shapeArgs.r,
            r2 = series2.points[0].shapeArgs.innerR,
            center = series1.center;

        console.log(series1);

        [0, 90, 180, 270].forEach(angle => {
            var rad = angle * Math.PI / 180;
            var path = renderer.path([
                'M',
                center[0] + r2 * Math.cos(rad),
                center[1] + r2 * Math.sin(rad),
                'L',
                center[0] + r1 * Math.cos(rad),
                center[1] + r1 * Math.sin(rad)
            ]).attr({
                'stroke-width': 4,
                stroke: 'grey'
            }).add(series2.group);
        })

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by my self
Add these event to load and redraw for resize events :-

**Html Part**

```
<chart [options]="chart1" class="highchart_container charthigh" (load)="saveChart($event.context)" (redraw)="saveChart($event.context)"> </chart>
```

**export class part**

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.chart1 = {
          chart: {
            type: 'pie',           
          },
          title : 'test',
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              shadow: false,
              center: ['50%', '50%'],
                size:'250'
            }
          },
          series: [{
            data: [14,14],
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '95%',        
          },
            {
              data: [21,7],
              size: '82%',
              innerSize: '95%',
            }]
        };
    }
chart1: Object;
    saveChart(chart1) {
/*here on chart1 object you get its position and set the html by using jquery below is my chart center points*/
var textX1 = chart1.plotLeft + (chart1.plotWidth  * 0.5);
         var textY1 = chart1.plotTop  + (chart1.plotHeight * 0.5) + $('.weeks-check-box').height();
}
```